# Visual tree not showing in MongoDB Compass "Explain Plan" tab

Tags: mongodb

When trying to see the visual tree this error appears:
**Visual explain plan is not supported with this query on this collection in this Compass release. Please refer to the raw json output of the explain for insight into the operation.**

This appears on any type of query and on any collection I have.

Is there anything to do?

Comment: This happens when you use Compass on a federated Atlas database.